# ZPL script for label triple

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I'm getting trouble printing some labels with a Zebra GK420t.

I have the next designer and how I need to print:
[image]

And the Zebra Designer Essentials generate the next ZPL script:

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR3,3~SD23^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW192
^LL0823
^LS0
^FT109,754^A0B,28,28^FH\^FDTEXTHERE^FS
^FT109,482^A0B,28,28^FH\^FDTEXTHERE^FS
^FT109,211^A0B,28,28^FH\^FDTEXTHERE^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

but it only print the center text and it vertically.

What is wrong with my ZPL/design?

It is my first time with this kind of printer, so i'm very newbie and I need use Browser Print, using a Javascript Library, and all ok here. But when I printed it, everything is wrong:

- Only print center text
- It prints vertically
- Text is cut

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The text is vertical because of the `B` in the `^A0B,28,28` font commands, which specifies to rotate the text 270 degrees.  But more importantly, it appears you are trying to print on different labels using a single format.  That is not possible (unless the labels are three across).

Comment: Thanks!. About the B it works!. Do you know how I can print in different label with a ZPL script?. I need use Browser Print but always take the center label, left and right always is missing.

Comment: To verify, are the labels three across? Or standard (just one across on the roll)?  This is confusing because the ZPL is trying to print the three strings vertically lower and lower, but you keep talking about left and right labels...

Comment: It is three across. Like the first image in post.

Comment: Ok, so a couple of things to look at.  First, is the `^PW192` command.  That will limit the rendered print width.  I think 192 is the width of one label?  You need to set it to the width of the roll.  And then, as mentioned previously, the `^FT` command is positioning the text strings lower and lower.  Do you have the x and y reversed on those?

Comment: I haven't. It was generated by Zebra Designer, I do not know much about ZPL scripts. I only see the visual view in that program. The width of roll is 102mm, height 24mm. Every label is 32mm x 22mm. Gap between label 2mm and margin of roll 1mm. That was the configuration I put in Designer and that ZPL was generated.

Answer (score 1):

What Mark said is correct, but what I want to add is that I've the feeling you created the label in zebradesigner using the landscape orientation and this explains the B parameter and also why the three text fields are vertically aligned instead of being horizontally aligned.

What you can do instead of trying to manually correct the ZPL code, is to generate a new label using zebradesigner, but setting the orientation to portrait and unselecting the "rotated" option.
[image]

Second thing is to configure the label layout in this way, just changing the dimension and the horizontal gap according to the labels you have.
[image]
This should generate a valid ZPL code.